# Must programatically set a grid to editable=false

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Super easy concept !...

At some point, my editable grid, (and detail grids), must be set to read only... so i would like to do something like:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.options.editable = false;
```

Of course this doesn't work as it would be too simple...

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would propose you having two grids: one read-only and one read-write but only one is visible. Both share the DataSource definition, so they are always in sync. When you want to change from one to the other, you hide the visible and display the other.

Example: I create two grids, exactly the same definition and just differ in that one is hidden and one is visible, one is editable and one is not. Since both share the same DataSource it actually works perfect because changing page in one changes in the other, editing one, updates the other.

Something like:

1- A CSS definition used for toggling visibility:

```
.ob-hide {
    display : none;
}
```

2- A DataSource definition:

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport : {
        read : {
            url: ...
        },
        update : {
            url: ...
        },
        create : {
            url: ...
        },
        destroy : {
            url: ...
        }
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            id : ...,
            fields: {
                id       : { type: '...' },
                ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Next the two grids:

```
$("#grid-editable").kendoGrid({
    editable: "inline",
    dataSource : ds,
    ...
}

$("#grid-not-editable").kendoGrid({
    editable: false,
    dataSource: ds,
    ...
});

$("#grid-editable").addClass("ob-hide");
```

And finally the function for switching modes:

```
function gridEditable() {
    $("#grid-editable").removeClass("ob-hide");
    $("#grid-not-editable").addClass("ob-hide");
});

function gridNotEditable() {
    $("#grid-editable").addClass("ob-hide");
    $("#grid-not-editable").removeClass("ob-hide");
});
```

See it running here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/bCEJR/2/

Comment: This is a great fix... I also got the solutions for Kendo to destroy the editable grid to recreate if in non editable mode... which i did since i had no other option. Thanks again OnaBai.

Comment: is there any other way of achieving this? I do not want to add two grid. I want to disable the existing grid.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked on a better style, by adding the `disabled="disabled"` on the elements needed. Using **angular JS** with **kendo**, worked like a charm, as by setting the grid to disabled doesn't allow the user to edit it. Try it, might work without angular as well!